# How to fit text properly inside a div with overflow: hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, dropdown

I'm having problems with the text inside a div with overflow: hidden.
The div is a dropdown that shows another div containing an image and text. The dropdown works with javascript editing height. There is also a problem; once in a while when I click on the drop button, it takes two clicks for it to work, I don't know why.

```
<div class="dropDiv">
<strong class="divTitle">Title</strong>
<div class="dropDownBtn" onclick="dropDown()"></div>
<br>
<div class="heroInfoDiv">
<img height="100%" width="20%" src="Media/image/img.png">
<div class="textHolder">If this text is too long, it dissapears.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

At first I tried having the div holding the text as a p-element, but changing it to div with any kind of CSS on it didn't work. What I want to happen is for the text to obey the rules of like any normal container, where it breaks lines automatically.

Here is a jsFiddle showing what is happening:
https://jsfiddle.net/56oypcbj/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `float: left` form your `.textHolder` class.

```
.textHolder {
  padding: 0px;
}
```